# Import Titanic dataset

Tags: python, dataset, pycharm, data-science

I'm just getting started with data science, and I'm planning to give the Titanic problem a shot. However, I don't really understand how I should import the dataset, or even where to store the downloaded dataset. Right now I created a folder in my DataScience-folder named input and stored the training set and the test-set in it. But when I'm in pyCharm I can't find this folder.

I tried to write the code

```
dataset = pd.read_cvs(.../input/train.cvs)
```

But it just says

> "Unsolved reference 'train'

, so where should I save my dataset and how can I access it in Python?

Comment: First of all, it's csv not cvs. Next, your file or file path should be a string, so put quotations around it `dataset = pd.read_csv(".../input/train.csv" )`.  Once you have done that, your dataset is saved in memory and you're ready to go! You might want to make a new folder called output to save your output once you are done with your analysis.

Comment: This [page from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic#tutorials) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I will try looking for working directory. Working directory is the place which is default folder for an environment. If you dont know your working directory, then this might help you

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Also, you can use default address to the file by see its location in windows folder by simply going to the address bar and copying it and pasting it like this:

```
dataset = pd.read_cvs(C:/Users/'username'/Desktop/input/train.cvs)
```

Give the full address and I think it should work.
Also, since you are new, using Jupyter Hub Notebook is more easier that pycharm. This is my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

you forget the quotation marks
 dataset = pd.read_csv('.../input/train.cvs',encoding = "utf-8",header = None)